# Using equal(),find() on a vector<complex <double> >

Tags: c++, stl, find, complex-numbers

This is a pretty straightforward thing, but I've been bashing my head trying to understand. I'm trying to compare the elements of a `vector<complex <double> >` vec with a `complex <double>` num to check if num already exists on vec. If it does, it is not added. I tried to use the equal() and algorithm, with no success. Does anybody knows a fast way to do that?

**EDIT2 :** I'm trying to do that for complex numbers as a simplification, as I also need to perform the same operation on a struct:

```
struct thing{
 int i;
 int j;
 complex <double> pos;
}typedef t_thing;

complex <double> new_num(2.0,2.0);
t_thing will_insert;
will_insert.i = 1;
will_insert.j = 1;
will_insert.pos = new_num;
vector<t_thing> vec_thing;
if(! (find(vec_thing.begin(),vec_thing.end(),will_insert) == vec_thing.end())){
  vec_thing.push_back(will_insert);
}else { 
 cout<<"element already on vec_thing"<<endl;
}
```

**EDIT 3:** I've overloaded the operator ==, but find cannot work with that:

```
: error: no matching function for call to ‘find(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<thing*, std::vector<thing, std::allocator<thing> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<thing*, std::vector<thing, std::allocator<thing> > >, t_thing&)’
```

Comment: `std::find` does not return a boolean - it returns an iterator.  If the iterator points to vec.end(), then you know the element does not exist in the vector.  Otherwise, `find` will return an iterator pointing to the located element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::equal` algorithm is used to compare 2 iterator ranges.  So you would use it to compare, for example, 2 vectors to see if both vectors contain the same elements.

In your case, where you only need to check if a single element is inside the vector, you can just use `std::find`

```
if (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::complex<double>(1,1)) == vec.end()) {
   /* did not find element */
}
else { /* found the element */ }
```

Note however that `std::vector` is not particularly well suited for lookup algorithms like this, since each lookup gives you O(N) complexity.  You might want to think about using `std::set`, so you get logarithmic complexity for lookup, and automatic assurance that you don't have any duplicate elements.

Comment: +1 for using set if the OP is trying to enforce a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Just realized that this contained my answer already :sigh:. Deleted my answer and +1.

Comment: While std::complex can be compared with operator==, it is stated that the comparison operator returns **lhs.real() == rhs.real() && lhs.imag() == rhs.imag()**. Since instantiating std::complex with anything but a floating point type is undefined, I would assume this can lead to the usual floating point comparison issues. Wouldn't a custom comparison function be in ordr here?

Comment: Or, if insertions are relatively infrequent or the container is relatively small, a sorted `std::vector` may provide better performance (using `std::binary_search` and friends).

Comment: The g++ compiler keeps giving me errors about the compilation, saying that there is no matching function to call for complex <double>. It works for double. The floating point comparison problems can also appear.

Comment: Also, it seems that using set, the order of the elements is changed, and I have to keep the insertion order.

Comment: @Ivan, if you need to keep insertion order, then you'll have to settle for O(N) lookups, without having some kind of external index.  Just use std::find with the vector.

Comment: @Charles, thank you. What kind of operator overload do I have to implement so find can work with the struct?

Comment: @Ivan, you can overload the equality (`==`) operator for your `struct thing`, so that `std::find` knows how to compare two `struct things`